# Does method signature influence Eclipse resource plugin loading order?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

EDIT 3 :
Obviously method signature cannot directly influence this loading order. My mistake was related to the fact that this static method was strongly coupled to the bundle activator... putting org.eclipse.core.resources at the very beginning loading stage. As far as I have understood, changing method parameter type forced a cast in calling method from Activator which introduced this earlier loading. I've made some refactoring in order to avoid this problem : bundle activator does not reference any core.resources classes anymore.

I have this static getter method in an Eclipse RCP application:

```
public static boolean isTrialDone(IFolder trialFolder) {
    ...
}
```

The application is running fine.

If I only change the method parameter type to `IResource`:

```
public static boolean isTrialDone(IResource trialFolder) {
    ...
}
```

I get this exception:

```
....
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The instance data location has not been specified yet.
....
```

Meaning the Resource plug-in has been started too earlier before the workspace location has been set.

But how can the parameter type influence the plug-in loading order?
Does the method signature influence Eclipse resource plug-in loading order?

EDIT : complete stack trace (EDIT 2 : Removed -> too long)

EDIT 2 : I've activated debug trace for DEBUG_LOADER

Here is the filtered (only related to my bundle) and truncated trace when parameter is of IFolder type (application is running fine) :

```
ModuleClassLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier].loadClass(the.bundle.package.BundleApplication)
BundleLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier].findClassInternal(the.bundle.package.BundleApplication)
BundleLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier].findLocalClass(the.bundle.package.BundleApplication)
ModuleClassLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier - /Path/To/Project/Workspace].findClassImpl(the.bundle.package.BundleApplication)
ModuleClassLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier].loadClass(org.eclipse.equinox.app.IApplication)
BundleLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier].findClassInternal(org.eclipse.equinox.app.IApplication)
BundleLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier] loading from required bundle package: org.eclipse.equinox.app -> [org.eclipse.equinox.app_1.3.400.v20150715-1528]
ModuleClassLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier].loadClass(java.lang.Object)
BundleLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier].findClassInternal(the.bundle.package.Activator)
BundleLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier].findLocalClass(the.bundle.package.Activator)
ModuleClassLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier - /Path/To/Project/Workspace].findClassImpl(the.bundle.package.Activator)
ModuleClassLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier].loadClass(org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin)
BundleLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier].findClassInternal(org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin)
BundleLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier] loading from required bundle package: org.eclipse.ui.plugin -> [org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.110.0.v20170612-1255]
BundleLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier] found local class the.bundle.package.Activator 
ModuleClassLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier].loadClass(org.eclipse.core.runtime.IStatus)
BundleLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier].findClassInternal(org.eclipse.core.runtime.IStatus)
BundleLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier] loading from required bundle package: org.eclipse.core.runtime -> [org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.9.0.v20170207-1454,org.eclipse.equinox.registry_3.7.0.v20170222-1344,org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.13.0.v20170207-1030]
ModuleClassLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier].loadClass(java.lang.Runnable)
ModuleClassLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier].loadClass(java.lang.Throwable)
ModuleClassLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier].loadClass(org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException)
BundleLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier].findClassInternal(org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException)
BundleLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier] loading from required bundle package: org.eclipse.core.runtime -> [org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.9.0.v20170207-1454,org.eclipse.equinox.registry_3.7.0.v20170222-1344,org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.13.0.v20170207-1030]
ModuleClassLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier].loadClass(java.util.Collection)
ModuleClassLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier].loadClass(java.lang.Exception)
ModuleClassLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier].loadClass(java.util.Comparator)
ModuleClassLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier].loadClass(org.eclipse.ui.PartInitException)
BundleLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier].findClassInternal(org.eclipse.ui.PartInitException)
BundleLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier] loading from required bundle package: org.eclipse.ui -> [org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.110.0.v20170612-1255]
ModuleClassLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier].loadClass(java.lang.String)
BundleLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier] found local class the.bundle.package.BundleApplication 
ModuleClassLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier].loadClass(org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor)
BundleLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier].findClassInternal(org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor)
BundleLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier] loading from required bundle package: org.eclipse.ui.application -> [org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.110.0.v20170612-1255]
ModuleClassLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier].loadClass(the.bundle.package.ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor)
BundleLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier].findClassInternal(the.bundle.package.ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor)
....
```

And here is the whole filtered trace when parameter is of IResource type (application stops because IResource needs to be loaded too earlier) :

```
ModuleClassLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier].loadClass(the.bundle.package.BundleApplication)
BundleLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier].findClassInternal(the.bundle.package.BundleApplication)
BundleLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier].findLocalClass(the.bundle.package.BundleApplication)
ModuleClassLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier - /Path/To/Project/Workspace].findClassImpl(the.bundle.package.BundleApplication)
ModuleClassLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier].loadClass(org.eclipse.equinox.app.IApplication)
BundleLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier].findClassInternal(org.eclipse.equinox.app.IApplication)
BundleLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier] loading from required bundle package: org.eclipse.equinox.app -> [org.eclipse.equinox.app_1.3.400.v20150715-1528]
ModuleClassLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier].loadClass(java.lang.Object)
BundleLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier].findClassInternal(the.bundle.package.Activator)
BundleLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier].findLocalClass(the.bundle.package.Activator)
ModuleClassLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier - /Path/To/Project/Workspace].findClassImpl(the.bundle.package.Activator)
ModuleClassLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier].loadClass(org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin)
BundleLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier].findClassInternal(org.eclipse.ui.plugin.AbstractUIPlugin)
BundleLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier] loading from required bundle package: org.eclipse.ui.plugin -> [org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.110.0.v20170612-1255]
BundleLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier] found local class the.bundle.package.Activator 
ModuleClassLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier].loadClass(org.eclipse.core.runtime.IStatus)
BundleLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier].findClassInternal(org.eclipse.core.runtime.IStatus)
BundleLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier] loading from required bundle package: org.eclipse.core.runtime -> [org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.9.0.v20170207-1454,org.eclipse.equinox.registry_3.7.0.v20170222-1344,org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.13.0.v20170207-1030]
ModuleClassLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier].loadClass(java.lang.Runnable)
ModuleClassLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier].loadClass(java.lang.Throwable)
ModuleClassLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier].loadClass(org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException)
BundleLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier].findClassInternal(org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException)
BundleLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier] loading from required bundle package: org.eclipse.core.runtime -> [org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.9.0.v20170207-1454,org.eclipse.equinox.registry_3.7.0.v20170222-1344,org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.13.0.v20170207-1030]
ModuleClassLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier].loadClass(java.util.Collection)
ModuleClassLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier].loadClass(java.lang.Exception)
ModuleClassLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier].loadClass(java.util.Comparator)
ModuleClassLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier].loadClass(org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource)
BundleLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier].findClassInternal(org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource)
BundleLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier] loading from required bundle package: org.eclipse.core.resources -> [org.eclipse.core.resources_3.12.0.v20170417-1558]
ModuleClassLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier].loadClass(org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource) failed.
ModuleClassLoader[Bundle_1.0.0.qualifier].loadClass(the.bundle.package.BundleApplication) failed.
```

Trace beginning is exactly the same upto org.eclipse.core.runtime which needs to load IResource class which triggers org.eclipse.core.resources loading.

But why org.eclipse.core.runtime needs to load IResource in this case and not IFolder in the previous one ? This a very tricky behaviour and I would really appreciate any help to understand where is my mistake !

Comment: No, the method signature does not influence loading order. Show us the complete stack trace.

Comment: I've just entered (almost) complete stack trace.

Comment: This is saying that the location of the workspace has not been specified (using `-data` or something like that). It is nothing to do with loading order.

Comment: I agree with you. But why is it working with IFolder and not with IResource parameter type ?

Comment: Is the method with `IFolder` actually being called? The error is occurring during lazy plugin activation, if the IFolder class was never actually loaded (and nothing else from the resource plugin was used) then the activation would not happen and there would be no error.

Comment: This is the SAME method. When I run the app. from Eclipse with IFolder parameter, no problem. If I change parameter type of the SAME method from IFolder to IResource, the exception occurs !

Comment: If it works with `IFolder`, it should also work with the more general type `IResource` (`IFolder` extends `IContainer` extends `IResource`). I guess the problem has nothing to do with the parameter type used.

Comment: Yes, you're right ! Any advice on how to debug ? The stack trace is huge ! Any tracing to enable ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have edited the question in order to add DEBUG_LOADER trace.